# Create a table from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following two tables:

1. Products with columns `p_id` and `name`
2. Users with columns `u_id` and `password`

I want to create a 3rd table named review, which will have the following 3 columns: `p_id`, `u_id`, `review`. The `p_id` and `u_id` are taken from products and users table respectively, and would kind of create a Cartesian product of the above two tables with added third column to it. How can I do that?

Comment: You want a view, not a table

Comment: there are relation between the two table ? .. and for review which value you want assign ?

Comment: @j.kaspar Where would the view get the review column?

Comment: @Barmar I suppose, that the data for that column will be somehow generated, so it would be obtained the same way, as if it was inserted to the table. But that is only guess. From the question isn't really obvious what the review column should be/contain. Plus it sounds like the asker wants the database to do something, what it should not do - generate a data

Comment: @j.kaspar I expect it will be filled in when users submit reviews of products.

Comment: @Barmar well, if that is correct, than a view is of course a nonsense

Comment: Are you sure you need to fill in the table with the cross product? Why don't you just wait until a user submits a review, and then insert a row for that user+product?

Comment: @barmar, i wanted to do that because there are limited number of users, say 5, and if a user has not reviewed it, i want to display not reviewed in place of the review.

Comment: @ArpanDang You can do that by left joining the users and products table with the reviews table.

Comment: Otherwise, every time you add a user or product, you'll need to add new rows to the reviews table.

Answer (score 2):

You can create with select

```
create table3 (p_id int(1), u_id int(11), review varchar(64)); 
insert table3 select Products.p_id, Users.u_id, 'value_for_review'
from Products, Users
```

Comment: You need datatypes for all the columns.

Comment: @Bamar In "create as"  statement the columns datatype are not required, and as clause is optional ..

Comment: but you didn't write `create as`.

Comment: The point is that you didn't use a `SELECT` statement to provide the contents of the table. It should be `create table (columns...) select columns... from tables...`

Comment: @Barmar  I use Insert Table3 Select Products.p_id ... and so on  .. i use an insert select

Comment: If you don't put the `SELECT` statement in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, you have to give the datatypes.