# Fetch different data from the database for every list item which opens the same page

Tags: php, mysql

I have an index.php file and a details.php file, both of which retrieves data from the same table, products.
The index.php file shows a list of name of products using

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT name FROM products');
if($result)
{
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) 
{   
     echo '<li><a href="details.php>'.$obj->name.'</a></li>';
}
}
```

Now in details.php, i only want to display the details of the product whose name i clicked on. How do I achieve this?

Comment: use get or post method when you clicking on the name you want and get `details` from db like `SELECT * FROM products where  name like ''selectedName'`

Comment: Is your question from yesterday resolved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899536/create-a-table-from-2-different-tables?

Comment: @chris85 it wasn't resolved but i took barmar's suggestion to just add into the table as soon as a user gives a review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name in the link then use a parameterized query on the next page and get just that record.

```
echo '<li><a href="details.php?name=' . urlencode($obj->name) . '">'.$obj->name.'</a></li>';
```

on subsequent page:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM products where name = ? limit 1');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row); // or whatever you want to do with it, indexes will be by name because is associative.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Have a primary key in your database and put it in your url détails.php instead of pass your product name